# On the coequaliser of a kernel pair

Tags: category-theory

How does one prove the following statement about [kernel pairs](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair)?

> If a pair of parallel morphisms is a kernel pair and has a coequalizer, then it is the coequalizer of its kernel pair.

Comment: I've edited the statement on nLab to the correct statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't make any sense of this statement; in particular I don't understand what "it" refers to.

Here is the correct statement: suppose $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism with a kernel pair $g_1, g_2 : X \times_Y X \to X$ which is also the coequalizer of some other pair of maps $h_1, h_2 : Z \to X$. Then in fact $f$ must be the coequalizer of its kernel pair. For a proof, see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/).

Comment: "it" refers to the coequalizer, I guess.

Comment: @Berci: with that interpretation the statement seems clearly false to me.

Comment: Great, thanks; I'm glad to find out that the statement is as confusing as it looks.